# Regex custom url validator

Tags: regex

I need a custom validator for urls with 2 conditions:
first condition - it starst with `http(s)://`
second condition the left part of url, before first single slash (or till the end of line if single slash not detected) should NOT contain whitespace, but after slash (if such exist), whitespace should be allowed
example:

prohibited url:

1. https://www.exam  ple.com/
2. htt ps://www.example.com/

allowed url:

3. https://www.example.com/exam  ple
4. http://www.example.com

I wrote Regex expression
`^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)[\S]+\/?` 
but it fails with url in example 1.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Comment: I think this question is unique and unswer is usefull for many people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\S` matches a non whitespace char including a `/` so in the first example it will not cross the first whitespace but you get a partial match because there is no ending anchor `$`

One option is to match not a forward slash using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^/\s]+` matching not a whitespace char or `/`. Then optionally match a forward slash and use `.*` to match the rest of the string.

```
^https?://[^/\s]+(?:/.*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YCZD2Y/1)